# Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

I am trying to make sure the comment can belong to a post as well as have an ID belonging to each user. Meaning, I want to be able to just render the comments and have it say which user posted that comment. So far reading into other peoples issues with this same thing I still haven't been able to solve it! I appreciate any help and thanks in advance! The comments won't render on the Dashboard.

Here is my users_controller.rb (useful bits only),

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit ]

  after_action :signed_in_after_register, only: :create 

  def dashboard 
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
  end 

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :bio, :comments, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :age, :profile_picture, :post, :body)
    end
end
```

Here is my dashboard.html.erb,

```
<%- @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading-gray"> <%= image_tag @user.profile_picture.url(:thumb) %> <h5 class="user-name"><%= @user.name %></h5> <h6 class="time-posted"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></h6></div>
        <div class="panel-body"><%= link_to post.body, post %></div>
        <div class="panel-footer"> 
            <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
            <%= render post.comments %>
            <p class="Like-option">Like ·</p>
            <p class="comment-form">Comment - <%= @post.comments.count %></p>  
            <p class="view-option">· View</p>
            <p class="comment-profile-picture">
            <%= image_tag @user.profile_picture.url(:thumb) %></p>
            <div class="comments-stream">
            <%= render @post.comments %>
        </div>
        <div id="comments-form">
            <%=  render "comments/form", :post => post %>
        </div>  
    </div> 
<!-- Other non-comments related code here -->
<% end %>
```

EDIT: Here is my _comment.html.erb,

```
<div class="comment clearfix">
    <div class="comment_content">
        <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>

        <% if @user_signed_in %>
            <p><%= link_to "Delete", [comment.post, comment],
                        method: :delete, 
                        class: "button",
                        data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
            </p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

and just in case here is my form for the comments _form.html.erb,

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Write a comment!" %>
    </p>
    <br>
    <p> <%= f.submit %> </p>

<% end %>
```

If you need to see anymore code or anything at all just comment and let me know, Thank you all!

Comment: I specifically said in The comments won't render on the Dashboard. Which means its a problem with the only bit of code that is shown here so yes, I have tried to isolate. This question was posted in hopes of getting an answer, Not someone trying to play smart. So Thank you and have a good one.

Comment: The "only bit of code?" So is it in your UsersController, which you posted? Or your CommentsController? Or the view? Or are your routes bad? You posted all of that, apparently expecting people to wade through it even though you already "tried to isolate." And now you want to get an attitude about it? I don't think the problem is your code.

Comment: Pretty sure I'm looking for help, Have a good one.

Comment: As @MarsAtomic said, you've posted a lot of code to sift through - rather than just the portions of the files necessary  - but here's what I don't see: the `views/comments/_comment.html.haml` - as the way your code is written in show, that's what would render.  Additionally - you don't have a 'single' comment on the dashboard, so don't try searching for one.

Comment: When I don't look for it in the dashboard it gives me this error. 
undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I also added two new things on my question. Tell me if that helps! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you call `raise params.inspect` in your dashboard action, you'll see that there is no such attribute comment_id.  And yet, your `@comment` definition is trying to call one.  You don't need this at all.

Nowhere in your view are you even referencing `@comment`.  As for adding the username or picture of the user who posted the comment, you'll have to put that in your comment partial `views/comments/_comment.html.erb` - because that is what is being rendered, once for each comment.

someting like:

```
<div class="comment clearfix">
  <div class="comment_content">
    <p class="comment_body">
      <span class="commentor"><%= comment.user.name %></span>
      <span class="body"><%= comment.body %></span>
    </p>
    <% if @user_signed_in %>          
      <p><%= link_to "Delete", [comment.post, comment],
                    method: :delete, 
                    class: "button",
                    data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see what you're talking about but after making those changes I still get this error on the dashboard.
Showing C:/row/website/app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `user' for #<Comment:0x9eeba20>

Comment: So yeah... What do you think?